# How to make a specific type of collapsible header custom element in polymer 1.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to make my first custom element in polymer 1.0, a collapsible 2 part header pretty much exactly like this https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport , where the top portion is fixed, but the bottom portions height animates down to half its original height on scroll.

This is very noob, but I'm not sure the most efficient approach to this. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These resources should help quick-start you properly.

1. [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index.html?hl=en) (or use [Github version](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit))
2. [Polymer Seed Element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/seed-element)

Also helpful is the [Polymer Designer Tool](https://polymer-designer.appspot.com) and of course the [Polymer Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/).

If after you begin you have more specific questions, feel free to post them here and we will do our best to help you out!